# Types of group action observing the table of $G$ acting in $X$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, symmetric-groups, group-actions

I'm studying the group action of a group $G$ on a set $X=\{1,\dots,n\}$

For example taking a straightforward example with $G \leq S_4$:

$$X = \{1,2,3,4\} \quad G=\{e_4,(1,2),(3,4),(1,2)(3,4)\}$$
We can construct a group multiplication table based on the action of $G$ in $X$ to determine the group action type.

$$\begin{array}{|l|llll|}
\hline
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
\sigma_1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
\sigma_2 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 4 \\
\sigma_3 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 3 \\
\sigma_4 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 3 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

At first glance is not transitive since $\sigma.x\neq y \quad x,y\in X$ for example $\nexists \sigma\in G$ such that $\sigma \cdot 1 = \sigma(1) = 4$.

It is faithful: given $\sigma,\rho \in G$ there exists $x$ such that $\sigma\cdot x \neq \rho\cdot x$, formally, every row is different by at least one element.

It is not free, so it doesn't satisfy $\sigma \cdot x = \rho \cdot x \iff \sigma = \rho = e$. For example $\sigma_2(1) = \sigma_4(1)$ breaks the rule.

---

**Summarizing**, I want a general understanding of group action types. It seems that types of group actions follow a pattern if we observe the table of the action of $G$ on $X$.

**Transitive:** each column has each $x\in X$ once.

**Faithful:** each row is different by at least one element.

**Free:** each row is entirely different to others. (As a consequence every permutation is a derangement since it has no fixed points)

**Regular:** All the listed above, so the table forms a symmetric matrix.

---

I can give you a group with regular action, so the table follows the aforementioned criteria:

$$G=\{e_4, (1,2)(3,4),(1,3)(2,4),(1,4)(2,3)\}$$

$$\begin{array}{|l|llll|}
\hline
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
\sigma_1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
\sigma_2 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 3 \\
\sigma_3 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
\sigma_4 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

As you can see it satisfied the criteria above.

**Q: What if $X=G$? Would be that an automorphism ($G \times G \to G$)? If it's the case, then do bijections from $G$ to $G$ give the corresponding permutation?**

**Q:All the groups above were subgroups of the symmetric group on n symbols. If that wasn't the case, how would an example look like?**

**Q: Can we determine the action type by observing if the properties are satisfied in the table?**

**Q: Is there any alternative method to identify the group action of a G-set?**

Comment: Here's one simple thing. Using the fact that $S_n$ acts faithfully on the set $X = \{1,...,n\}$ it follows that for every subgroup $G \le S_n$, the restricted action of $G$ on $X$ is also faithful.

Comment: Yes I knew that one. Being faithful means that gives us different permutations as I explained above, maybe as my second question says, is it enough that the action is faithful to have an embedding. But my main concern and question here if it's my understanding on group actions is right, and if the construction with tables is also certain.

Comment: In your question as stated, $G$ is given as a subgroup of $S_n$. So $G$ is automatically embedded into $S_n$, as is every subgroup of every group. It sounds like in the back of your mind you might be thinking about the more general concept of a group action; however, that is not how you wrote the question.

Comment: Oh yes, this question just shows some examples in order to define types of action. But in the end  I'm working on the general abstract concept of a group, gonna remove the boundary of $G$ being a subgroup of $S_n$

Comment: The question still isn't clear to me: What do you mean by your "construction" exactly? The description of various properties in terms of the rows of the table recording the action? And in what sense is this a classification?

Comment: _The description of various properties in terms of the rows of the table recording the action?_ Yes. Each column is the orbit of a fixed element $x\in X$. Each row is the action of a fixed $\sigma$ by each element in $X$. Maybe _classification_ is not the best term. I'm trying to see what the type of the action is by examining such a table.

Comment: @Travis: do the context, description and questions seem more concise now?